# registration android app without internet connection

Tags: php, android, logic

I have an Android registration app. When both the mobile device and computer are connected on same wifi it runs fine. But if Internet connection of mobile device turns off, there appears a toast message

> 'java.net.ConnectException:failed to connect to/100.118.242.179(port 80) after 2500ms: isConnected failed:
>   ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)'.

```
public class AppConfig
{
    public static String URL_LOGIN="http://100.118.242.179/android_login_api/login.php";

    public static String URL_REGISTER="http://100.118.242.179/android_login_api/register.php";
}
```

How to run the app without Internet connection on mobile device?

Comment: you have web server on your computer?

Comment: @Godot don't you?

Answer (score 2):

In your app make a database and store in it the login data you get back from the login site(session key, authentication token, user profile, whatever)

If the connection is offline and the user has already logged in once without logging out, read the data from the database and assume good faith usage and just work as usual.

If the user has never logged in before, you could have a "default" user that gives limited functionality, popping up the register/signin window when connection is restored.

**unrelated noted I feel important to mention**
Also, make sure your IPV4 address is truly fixed and not from some assigned IP from an ISP that might shuffle around IPV4 blocks or hide you behind the ISP NAT(this means that connection attempts will usually get served to the last customer added to the NAT pool, which may or not be you)
Use a service like duckdns or dyndns if you are behind a home server or use an IPV6 address that is more likely to stay stable.